# Problem regarding vanishing set of convolution

Tags: real-analysis, lebesgue-measure, convolution

Let $f$ vanishes on an open set containing 0. So there exists $l>0$ such that $f$ vanishes on $B(0,2l).$ So we can choose $g\in C_c^\infty (\mathbb{R}^n)$ (supported on $B(0,l)$) such that $f*g$ vanishes on an open set ( vanishes on $B(0,l)$).

My question: Is it remains true if we replace open set by set of positive Lebesgue measure i.e. if $f$ vanishes on an positive Lebesgue measure set around 0, then can we find a nonzero $g\in C_c^\infty (\mathbb{R}^n)$ such that $f*g$ vanishes on a set of positive Lebesgue measure?

Comment: Yes, e.g. we can take $g$ identically 0

Comment: I have edited the question, adding the condition for $g$ to be nonzero.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As noted in Pietro Majer's comment, you can trivially take $g=0$ to get the "yes" answer.

To avoid this and make the question less trivial, one may additionally require that the function $g$ be nonnegative and nonzero. Then the answer becomes "no".

Indeed, e.g. let
$$f:=1_{D},$$
where $D:=\mathbb R\setminus C$ and $C$ is a [fat Cantor subset](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smith%E2%80%93Volterra%E2%80%93Cantor_set) of the interval $[0,1]$, so that $C$ is a closed nowhere dense set of positive (Lebesgue) measure and hence $D$ is an everywhere dense open set.

So, $f=0$ on the set $C$ of measure $|C|>0$.

Now, take any nonnegative nonzero continuous function $g\colon\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$, so that for some real $c>0$ we have $g\ge c$ on a nonempty open interval $I$. Then, for any real $x$,
$$(f*g)(x)=\int_{\mathbb R}f(x-y)g(y)\,dy \\ 
\ge
c\int_I f(x-y)\,dy=c|D\cap(x-I)|>0,$$
because $D$ is an everywhere dense open set and hence $D\cap(x-I)$ is a nonempty open interval.

Thus, $f>0$ on $\mathbb R$.

Comment: Good point, but what if all that is required of $g$ is that it is smooth, compactly supported, and not identically zero, which, most likely, was the original intention?

Comment: @fedja : I think this is a good question. I did think about it, but at this point don't know an answer to it.

Comment: Yes, I was looking for the answer for any non-zero $C_c^\infty$ function. But any way thanks for your efforts. Please update your answer if you able to make some progress.

Comment: @Wilderness : This is indeed a good question, and I will have it in mind.